# Civilization Board Game - founding cities gives army extra move?

Tags: civilization-board-game

**Sid Meier's Civilization: The Board Game (2010)**

Let's say I have just moved an army and a scout together on a tile. Then, in the Starting Phase of the next turn, I found a city with the scout, and the manual states that the army has to *immediately* move out of the city onto a valid tile where it can end its turn.

[Manual](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/1a/10/1a1063a1-ee84-44ac-a79a-237277010a6f/civ_rulebook_eng_lo-res.pdf), page 13:

> If there are any friendly figures in the square where a city
>   is being built besides the scout being sacrificed, the player
>   immediately moves them to an adjacent square that they can
>   legally end their movement in.

But the Movement Phase has not yet begun!

- So does this moving out of the tile cost the points that are used in
  the Movement Phase? The Movement Phase description doesn't seem to
  mention this possibility.
- Otherwise, doesn't this add an extra movement point? That seems like
  an exploit.
- Or does this mean that that army ends its movement prematurely in
  this turn, ahead of the movement phase?

Or how should this be handled? Haven't found anything on this in the [Errata / FAQs](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/4e/a4/4ea4c8a6-7cf2-45b1-9dc3-6a72994644ff/civilization_faq_v20.pdf), either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Those units can still move their full Travel Speed during the Movement Phase.**

In the first paragraph of the rules regarding movement on page 19, the rulebook has this to say (emphasis mine):

> During this phase, each player, in turn, may move ***all*** of their figures, one at a time.

The rulebook doesn't go on to restrict which units constitute "all" units. Given the verbiage here, you should be able to move any units that were displaced when a city was built. The rules are also pretty explicit in that a unit can't split its movement points to perform other actions:

> Once a figure has begun its move, it must complete its move before any other figure may move.

So you also wouldn't subtract movement points from those units during the Movement Phase.

The rule you quoted ends by saying that the units have to go where "they can legally end" their movement. This is meant to prevent units from being able to end a turn on an illegal space should the player decide not to move those units during the Movement Phase.